# Rust nalgebra inverse matrix

Tags: matrix, rust, nalgebra

Does anyone no a simple way to get the inverse of a matrix using the Rust nalgebra::Matrix ?
I'm trying to do this the same way as with the C++ Eigen library but clearly not working.

#cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
nalgebra = "0.30"
```

#main.rs

```
let mut m = Matrix3::new(11, 12, 13,
                    21, 22, 23,
                    31, 32, 33);    

println!("{}", m);
println!("{}", m.transpose());
println!("{}", m.inverse()); // This blows up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nalgebra's Matrix does not have a straight-up inverse method, mainly because matrix inversion is a fallible operation. In fact, the example matrix doesn't even have an inverse. However, you can use the `try_inverse` method:

```rust
let inverse = m.try_inverse().unwrap();
```

You can also use the `pseudo_inverse` method if that's better for your usecase:

```rust
let pseudo_inverse = m.pseudo_inverse().unwrap();
```

Note that the pseudoinverse is unlikely to fail, see `nalgebra::linalg::SVD` if you want more fine-grained control of the process.

Another note is that you have a matrix of integers, and you need a matrix of floats, although that's an easy fix- just add some decimal points:

```rust
let m = Matrix3::new(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e34eebdb69cc8350d1fb3675e9eb172)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I saw try_inverse() but this does not seem to work even in your playground?  ^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Matrix<{integer}, ...` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

Comment: @sbeskur you can't invert a matrix of integers, you need to use a matrix of floats. See the note at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: totally missed it.  Thanks man.